# Validator, what's wrong?

Tags: php, octobercms

I'm going a little be crazy with my simple validator.

```
$data = ['dam' => 1, 'sir' => 2];
$v = Validator::make(
        $data, 
        ['dam' => 'exists:individuals,id'],
        ['dam.exists' => 'Object not found']
);

$validateLab = $v->validate();
dd($validateLab);
```

In the table individuals, there is an entry for id=1, but not id=2. If I run the code as it is, I get "true". If I change 'dam' => 1 to 'dam' => 2, I get

> "The given data was invalid." on line 306 of
>   /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/mysamples/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php :

```
...
/**
 * Run the validator's rules against its data.
 *
 * @return void
 *
 * @throws \Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException
 */
public function validate()
{
    if ($this->fails()) {
        throw new ValidationException($this);
    }
}
...
```

Why? Why it does not return "Object not found"?

Comment: `"The given data was invalid." on line 306 of ...` can you tell us exactly what is on line 306 please?

Comment: Hi. I updated the post with the code at line 306.